# Flutter package for foreground service flutter_foreground_task: ^3.10.0 not works in sdk 33

Tags: android, flutter, isolate

flutter_foreground_task: ^3.10.0 i used this package in flutter project there is a sendport and receiveport  callback sendport and recieve port not working in sdk 33 on release build it was crashing.

```
registerReceivePort(await FlutterForegroundTask.receivePort);  
registerReceivePort(ReceivePort? receivePort) {
//closeReceivePort();
if (receivePort != null) {
_receivePortForeground = receivePort;
_receivePortForeground?.listen((position) {
currentLatLng = LatLng(position!.latitude, position.longitude);
previousLatLngFromServer = currentLatLng;
Prefs().setLasKnowLatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
Prefs().setDouble(Prefs.bearing, position.heading);
if(isTripStarted && vehicleMarker!=null){
AnimateMarker(onMarkerPosUpdate: (Marker marker) {
locationMarkers.remove(vehicleMarker);
vehicleMarker = marker;
locationMarkers.add(vehicleMarker!);
googleMapController!
.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
CameraPosition(target: LatLng(vehicleMarker!.position.latitude,vehicleMarker!.position.longitude), zoom: 16.5)));
notifyListeners();
}).animaterMarker(vehicleMarker!.position,currentLatLng, vehicleMarker!);
findSegment();
}
updateLocationToServer();
});
}
}
void closeReceivePort() {
_receivePortForeground?.close();
_receivePortForeground = null;
}
```